# TSQL - in a string, replace a character with a fixed one every 2 characters

Tags: t-sql, overlap

I can't replace every 2 characters of a string with a '.'

> select STUFF('abcdefghi', 3, 1, '.') c3,STUFF('abcdefghi', 5, 1,
> '.') c5,STUFF('abcdefghi', 7, 1, '.') c7,STUFF('abcdefghi', 9, 1, '.')
> c9

if I use STUFF I should subsequently overlap the strings c3, c5, c7 and c9. but I can't find a method

can you help me?

initial string:

> abcdefghi

the result I would like is

> ab.de.gh.

the string can be up to 50 characters

Comment: sounds like you might benefit from a recursive CTE - however sample data and desired results would be useful as it's not clear what you mean.

Comment: the result I would like is 'ab.de.gh.'

Answer (score 1):

Create a numbers / tally / digits table, if you don't have one already, then you can use this to target each character position:

```
with digits as ( /* This would be a real table, here it's just to test */
    select n from (values(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10))x(n)
), t as (
    select 'abcdefghi' as s
)
select String_Agg( case when d.n%3 = 0 then '.' else Substring(t.s, d.n, 1) end, '')
from t
cross apply digits d
where d.n <Len(t.s)
```

Using `for xml` with existing table

```
with digits as (
    select n from (values(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10))x(n)
),
r as (
    select t.id, case when d.n%3=0 then '.' else Substring(t.s, d.n, 1) end ch
    from t
    cross apply digits d
    where d.n <Len(t.s)
)
select result=(select '' + ch
    from r r2
    where r2.id=r.id
    for xml path('')
)
from r
group by r.id
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. but i can't use string_agg for my sql server version

Comment: You're using an older version (2016 or earlier) in which case you can use the legacy `for xml` method instead

Comment: can you give me an example of use? in the past I have used for xml to concatenate records, but not to overlay results

Comment: @neotrojan Have edited above

Comment: if I replace 'abcdefghi' with a table eg. (select field from table) error "The subquery returned more than one value. This is not allowed for subqueries following the characters =,! =, <, <=,>,> = or used as an expression. " it only works if there is only one record

Comment: @neotrojan see additional edit!

Answer (score 0):

You can try it like this:

**Easiest might be a *quirky update* ike here:**

```
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(100)='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';

SELECT @string = STUFF(@string,3*A.pos,1,'.')
FROM (SELECT TOP(LEN(@string)/3) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
      FROM master..spt_values) A(pos);

SELECT @string;
```

**Better/Cleaner/Prettier was a recursive CTE:**

We use a declared table to have some tabular sample data

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY, SomeString VARCHAR(200));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES('')
                      ,('a')
                      ,('ab')
                      ,('abc')
                      ,('abcd')
                      ,('abcde')
                      ,('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz');
```

--the query

```
WITH recCTE AS
(
    SELECT ID
          ,SomeString 
          ,(LEN(SomeString)+1)/3 AS CountDots
          ,1 AS OccuranceOfDot
          ,SUBSTRING(SomeString,4,LEN(SomeString)) AS RestString
          ,CAST(LEFT(SomeString,2) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS Growing 
    FROM @tbl 

    UNION ALL

    SELECT t.ID
          ,r.SomeString
          ,r.CountDots
          ,r.OccuranceOfDot+2
          ,SUBSTRING(RestString,4,LEN(RestString)) 
          ,CONCAT(Growing,'.',LEFT(r.RestString,2)) 
    FROM @tbl t
    INNER JOIN recCTE r ON t.ID=r.ID
    WHERE r.OccuranceOfDot/2<r.CountDots-1
)
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES ID,Growing 
FROM recCTE
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY OccuranceOfDot DESC);
```

--the result

```
1   
2   a
3   ab
4   ab
5   ab
6   ab.de
7   ab.de.gh.jk.mn.pq.st.vw.yz
```

The idea in short

- We use a recursive CTE to walk along the string
- we add the needed portion together with a dot
- We stop, when the remaining length is to short to continue
- a little magic is the `ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER()` together with `TOP 1 WITH TIES`. This will allow **all** first rows (*frist per ID*) to appear.